# Is a Git submodule an independent repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I look at my Git repository I can see that there is a .git folder inside the main repository. Then, when I goto into the submodule, I can see there is no folder called .git but there is a file called .git. Why this difference?

If the submodule is an actual repository like the main repository and can be worked on basically independent of the main repository, shouldn't both have a .git folder or both have .git file and not be different like this?

Comment: Yes it is indeed an independent repository. If you open the inner `.git` file you will notice it refers to a subfolder in the top-level `.git` folder, namely `.git/modules/*`. But yes, in other words you could `git clone` *just* the submodule as it's own repo if you wanted to do development just on that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every Git submodule is an independent repository.  What you're seeing is called a gitlink, and it's a way of making the `.git` contents point somewhere else.  The original idea was to use symlinks for this, but Windows requires elevated privileges or special settings to use symlinks, so Git had to use gitlinks instead.

The reason that you want to use gitlinks for submodules is because it makes it easier to deinitialize a submodule (that is, get rid of its contents) without blowing away its history.  If you have a gitlink, then as long as the working tree of the submodule is clean, deinitializing it is essentially just an `rm -fr` on the directory, which is very convenient.  Moreover, because people do exactly that sometimes with submodules, that means they haven't blown away their history unexpectedly.

It is still possible to use a separate `.git` directory if you want, but there's usually no good reason to do so unless for some reason your submodule is on a separate mount point.

If you want to find the actual Git directory of a repository, do this: `git rev-parse --git-dir` or `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`.

Answer (score 4):

The git storage directory for a submodule is stored within the `.git/` directory of the main repository.

You can find them under `.git/modules/` :

```
ls .git/modules
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every submodule is its own separate repository.

There was a period in early `git submodule` when it was like this: both the superproject and an every submodules have their own `.git` folders. Later it was decided that all `git`-related files should be stored under one `.git` directory even for submodules. So `git submodule` grew a subcommand [git submodule absorbgitdirs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-absorbgitdirs) that moves `.git` directories for submodules to the superproject's `.git/modules/` and leave a file `.git` that points to  the superproject's `.git/modules/`.

`git clone --recursive` does that (move to superproject's `.git/modules/`) automatically.